# Dropdown not showing data flutter

Tags: flutter

I am trying to show a data in dropdown menu,but i have a weird problem i can't seem to figure it out.The problem is when open the view that contained dropdown menu the api data fetch data from server,it work as excepted but the data not shows to the dropdown for first time,in debug mode when i press hot realod the data is shown to dropdown menu not when the view shows first time

**Dropdown menu**

```
                  Flexible(
                    flex: 0,
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: Container(
                        height: 45,
                        width: 300,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                            border: Border.all(
                                color: Color.fromRGBO(92, 52, 76, 1))),
                        child: DropdownButton<String>(
                            isExpanded: true,
                            itemHeight: 50,
                            underline: SizedBox(),
                            value: _selectedVehicle,
                            items: vehicle_list.map((vehicle) {
                              return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                                value: vehicle.id,
                                child: new Text(
                                  vehicle.model,
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 15,
                                      color: Color.fromRGBO(
                                          92, 52, 76, 1)),
                                ),
                              );
                            }).toList(),
                            hint: Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                              child: Text("Please Select Vehicle"),
                            ),
                            onChanged: (newValues) {
                              setState(() {
                                _selectedVehicle = newValues;
                              });
                            }),
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
```

API

```
Future<String> getVehicles() async {
    vehicle_list.clear();
    Future tokens = SharedPrefrence().getToken();
    tokens.then((data) async{
      token=data;
      var response = await http.get(Urls.BASE_URL + Urls.GET_VEHICLES, headers: {
        "Authorization": "Bearer " + token,
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      });
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        print("vechiles " + response.body.toString());
        Map<String, dynamic> value = json.decode(response.body);
        try {
          var data = value['data'];
          for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            var obj = data[i];
            vehicle_list.add(VehicleModel(
                obj['id'].toString(),
                obj['user_id'].toString(),
                obj['type'].toString(),
                obj['model'],
                obj['reg_no'],
                obj['fuel_type'].toString()));
          }
        } catch (e) {
          
          print(e.toString());
        }
      } else {
        print(response.body.toString());
      }
    });
  }
```

intilization

```
List<VehicleModel> vehicle_list = [];
String _selectedVehicle;
```

This how i call the function

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    getVehicles();
   
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this will resolve your issue:

```dart
Future<String> getVehicles() async {
    vehicle_list.clear();
    Future tokens = SharedPrefrence().getToken();
    tokens.then((data) async{
      token=data;
      var response = await http.get(Urls.BASE_URL + Urls.GET_VEHICLES, headers: {
        "Authorization": "Bearer " + token,
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      });
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        print("vechiles " + response.body.toString());
        Map<String, dynamic> value = json.decode(response.body);
        try {
          var data = value['data'];
          for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            var obj = data[i];
            vehicle_list.add(VehicleModel(
                obj['id'].toString(),
                obj['user_id'].toString(),
                obj['type'].toString(),
                obj['model'],
                obj['reg_no'],
                obj['fuel_type'].toString()));
          }
          
          // add this line...
          WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) => setState((){}));
        } catch (e) {
          
          print(e.toString());
        }
      } else {
        print(response.body.toString());
      }
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have call `setState` at the end of the function to modify the state!

Something like this,

```
Future<String> getVehicles() async {
    vehicle_list.clear();
    Future tokens = SharedPrefrence().getToken();
    tokens.then((data) async{
      token=data;
      var response = await http.get(Urls.BASE_URL + Urls.GET_VEHICLES, headers: {
        "Authorization": "Bearer " + token,
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      });
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        print("vechiles " + response.body.toString());
        Map<String, dynamic> value = json.decode(response.body);
        try {
          var data = value['data'];
          for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            var obj = data[i];
            vehicle_list.add(VehicleModel(
                obj['id'].toString(),
                obj['user_id'].toString(),
                obj['type'].toString(),
                obj['model'],
                obj['reg_no'],
                obj['fuel_type'].toString()));
          }
          setState(() {});
        } catch (e) {
          
          print(e.toString());
        }
      } else {
        print(response.body.toString());
      }
    });
  }
```

Hope that works!